# Как определить открыт ли файл для записи другим устройством?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Казалось бы элементарный вопрос, но во всем интернете, в т.ч. справках я не нашел на него ответа к сожалению... Вопрос уже задавался, но ответа на него я так и не получил.

Я примерно сделал код, как это бы выглядело на с++ например. Но я не пойму, он вроде работает, но в тоже время генерирует ошибку когда я пытаюсь закрыть файл... Если я не закрываю файл, ошибок не генерируется, но тогда смысл теряется в подобном использовании, так как суть этих действий как раз и состоит в контроле над открытием и закрытием файлов, во избежании конфуза с двумя одновременно записывающих устройств...

... и в случае если файл открыт на запись - ожидать, пока другое устройство не завершит процесс записи в открытый на запись файл...
Помогите мне как то разобраться или элементарным примером или же ссылкой на разъяснения по данному вопросу... В документации не разъясняется этот момент или же он хорошо скрыт...
В общем вот мой пример:

```
let fin = fs.openSync("./123.txt", "w");
if(fin){
    fs.writeFileSync("./123.txt", "Hello World !!!"); // Скорее всего здесь нужна какая то низкоуровневая функция на запись... не нашел пока...
    fs.closeSync(fin); // Предупреждения генерируются при закрытии файла !!!
}
```

Comment: Э? Так бы это выглядело в си? А вы точно умеете си? Мои воспоминания говорят что там где flock должен быть…

Comment: В си по-другому. В с++ примерно как я описал выше. если быть точнее, то:
ifstream fin;
fin.open("./123.txt", ios::in);
if(fin){
fin >> запись;
fin.close();
}
else{
cout << файл не открылся << endl;
}

Comment: Эм? Так чтение или запись?

Comment: Ну да ошибся.чтение меня не интересует в общем то. ну в общем то не суть.  ваша взяла)))

Comment: Ну знаете, чтение и запись это вообще разные вещи с разными подводными камнями…

Comment: Но в общем, `flock` в nodejs официально нет, есть сторонние пакеты (например `fs-ext`)

Comment: Понятное дело, что разные. Я этот язык достаточно хорошо знаю. Но концентрация у меня, особенно при задавании вопросов стремится к нулю и я могу писать дичь, за что и получаю соответствующие ответы... Но в целом ответ найден...

Comment: В общем то на этот вопрос ответили люди из другого моего вопроса. Ответ заключается в том, что js - однопоточный ЯП, и не может задействовать несколько потоков. Сама по себе асинхронность - это по сути переменная смена исполнения разных кусков кода по времени, на усмотрение проца. Итак, из этого следует, что каким бы ни был бы способ записи в файл он будет открыт, прочит и закрыт полностью прежде чем его будет записывать другой огрызок кода, главное по всей видимости заключать это все в бесконечный цикл ожидания, чтобы выполнялась проверка на занятость файла путем получения при открытии ошибок

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, получив дескриптор, лучше его и использовать, иначе не ясно, зачем он. То есть тут стоит не имя файла задавать, а дескриптор: `fs.writeFileSync(fin, "Hello World !!!");`.

Comment: Надо будет попробовать)))